# XAML Designer displays property name instead of Designer Data (d:DataContext) when Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

#### Context

I want my `UserControl` (`RepositoryContainer`) to be filled up with data when on XAML Designer.

I created a file named `RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml` (it is in the same folder as the `RepositoryContainer.xaml`) and set it as `d:DataContext` to the `UserControl`.

But instead of displaying the data, XAML Designer displays the property name.

Here's a minimal example:

#### Design Data (RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml)

```
<local:RepositoryContainer xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemSpecs.View.UserControls"
                           Title="My Repository Title"
/>
```

#### User Control (RepositoryContainer.xaml)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SystemSpecs.View.UserControls.RepositoryContainer"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemSpecs.View.UserControls"
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="500"
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml}"
                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### Code-behind

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SystemSpecs.View.UserControls
{
    public partial class RepositoryContainer : UserControl
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public RepositoryContainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

#### Output:

[image: Output]

#### Already tried:

- [Set `IsDesignTimeCreatable` as `true`:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947002/wpf-xaml-designer-showing-bound-property-names-instead-of-property-values)
- Closing Visual Studio and deleting `.vs` folder
- `RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml` `Build Action` is `DesignData`

#### Environment info:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Visual Studio Community 2015 (Version 14.9.25431.01 Update 3)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.01586
- More info at a [Pastebin RAW](http://pastebin.com/raw/whVX2esP) to keep post clean

**Am I missing something?**

#### PS

If I create a class (e.g. `public class RepositoryContainerData`), create a property called `Title` and set an instance of this class as `d:DataContext` (`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:RepositoryContainerData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`) it works as expected.

Comment: The solution from "PS" section is the correct approach. You don't create design user controls, you create Design Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use dependency properties in WPF usercontrols as they have change notification.

```
    public static DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(RepositoryContainer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Title_Changed)));

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void Title_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        RepositoryContainer thisClass = (RepositoryContainer)o;
        thisClass.SetTitle();
    }

    private void SetTitle()
    {
        //Put Instance Title Property Changed code here
    }
```

Just replace your **Title** property with the code above, nothing should have to be added to make it work. **SetTitle()** only needs code if you need to react to the Title changed in code.

I have a c# code snippet that I created a long time ago that can make dependency properties easily, just let me know if you want it.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do works for me with possibly some minor changes.  I created a new app called `WpfApplication2`.

`RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml` contains:

```
<wpfApplication2:RepositoryContainer 
    xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="My repository title">
</wpfApplication2:RepositoryContainer>
```

The file properties are set to:

[image]

The control definition is

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.RepositoryContainer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=RepositoryContainerDesignData.xaml}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="Bisque">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontSize="24" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The result in the designer is

[image]

Not something I would usually do but I've learned something :)