# WPF DesignInstace resulting in showing namespace of datacontext as string instead of binding result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, localization

Currently I having strange problem and trying the explain problem;

For design time, I am using following design instance on XAML side

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type viewmodels:AddMeasurementEnterDataBaseStep},
                                 IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

For localization of text using following binding extension

```
public class LocExtension : Binding
{
    public LocExtension(string name)
        : base("[" + name + "]")
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        this.Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
       
    }
}
```

the usage of LocExtension:  (Here, XYData key to resource, translated via resource manager)

```
<TextBlock Text="{ns:Loc XYData}" />
```

Everything works as expected during runtime, but at design time, it is displaying binding **source** as text.

**DesingTime:**

[image]

**RunTime**

[image]

Anyone facing similar issue?

**UPDATE** based on [the question ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947002/wpf-xaml-designer-showing-bound-property-names-instead-of-property-values)

I have seen that, I might be activating **'Enable Project Code in XAML'**. But it is somehow default deactivated:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot
> run project code in the designer, so the Disable project code button
> is disabled in the designer.

So, for X64 targeted projects, i have no chance :)